# Relation between inner product and wedge product

Tags: riemannian-geometry, exterior-algebra

$M$ is an Riemannian n-manifold, $p\in  M$. $x, y\in T_pM$. Is it true that $\langle x,x \rangle \langle y, y \rangle-\langle x, y \rangle^2=|x \wedge y|^2$?

I'm reading Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry and I don't quite understand how the wedge product is defined for tangent vectors and how it interacts with inner product.

Comment: Where in do Carmo is this?  You could do a wedge product on tangent vectors by taking the standard wedge product on cotangent vectors and using metric duality, but I don't do enough Riemannian geometry to know if that's a thing...